# p tag is appearing as a link when i click it take is me to the same link included in the div

Tags: html

I have a `<p>` tag that is appearing as a link and I can find out why

```html
<section>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <h3>Women and Tech</h3>
    <img src="images/placeholder-images/thumbnail-2.jpg" alt="description of image">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/"> Women and Tech Website</ a>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea"</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: He had the `<a>` tag wrong originally - He had `</ a>` which doesn't work to close the tab. You can see this in the edit history

Comment: @Shiny: Good catch, thanks!  (Makes the question closable as a typo now of course.)

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra space in your closing anchor tag.

```html
<section>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <h3>Women and Tech</h3>
    <img src="images/placeholder-images/thumbnail-2.jpg" alt="description of image">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/"> Women and Tech Website</a>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea"</p>
  </div>
</section>
```